# Content Spilling Overflowing Out of Div View Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a div using `height: 50vh;` but no matter what I try I can't get the content inside of it to stop from overflowing. Inside of the div I have another div that uses a background image and maintains a specific aspect ratio... it also uses an overflow scroll.

What I'm trying to do is have the content inside the top div resize on browser resize while maintaining the same aspect ratio.

Please let me know if this is possible and if so, how I can accomplish this.

Thanks!

Here is an example of what I have so far.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LaLqNZ

```css
    body,
    html {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    #wrap {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    #top {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 50vh;
      display: inline-block;
      background: blue;
      padding: 20px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    #bottom {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 50vh;
      display: inline-block;  
      background: green;  
    }
    
    .one {
      max-width: 450px;
      margin: auto;
    }
    
    .two {
      padding-top: 73%;
      display: block;
      margin: 0;
      background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/OQL0NR3.png);
      background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .three {
      position: absolute;
      top: 5.3%;
      right: 4%;
      bottom: 23.5%;
      left: 4%;
    }
    
    .four {
      max-height: 100%;
      overflow: scroll;
    }
    
    .four img {
      max-width: 100%;
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
 <div id="wrap">
     <div id="top">
      <div class="one">
       <div class="two">
           <div class="three">
              <div class="four"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/4yBw2n4.jpg"></div>
           </div>
         </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div id="bottom">
      <h1>Sample Text</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I cannot see any use of `max-height: 50vh;` in the source code provided here or from the [**codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LaLqNZ) link.

Comment: @NewToJS sorry I meant to say height: 50vh;.

Comment: When you say *"What I'm trying to do is have the content inside the top div resize on browser resize while maintaining the same aspect ratio."* Do you mean the computer monitor should resize with it?

Comment: @NewToJS yea, I would like the monitor to resize. The monitor displays properly when the browser width is resized... but it doesn't display properly when the browser height is resized. I hope I explained that right.

Answer (score 2):

I Hope this is the one you expected

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
setTimeout(function() { 
    resize();
}, 25);

});
    
function resize() {
var w = document.getElementById('monitor').width;
document.getElementById('two').setAttribute("style", "width: " + w + "px;")
}
```

```css
body,
html {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

#wrap {
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#top {
width: 100vw;
height: 50vh;
display: inline-block;
background: blue;
padding: 20px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#bottom {
width: 100vw;
height: 50vh;
display: inline-block;
background: green;
}

.one {
max-width: 450px;
height: 100%;
margin: auto;
}

.two {
display: block;
margin: auto;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
}

.three {
position: absolute;
top: 5.3%;
right: 4%;
bottom: 23.5%;
left: 4%;
}

.four {
max-height: 100%;
overflow: scroll;
}

.four img {
max-width: 100%;
display: block;
}

.monitor {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    width: 0 !important 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onresize="resize()">
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="top">
        <div class="one">
            <div id="two" class="two">
                <img id="monitor" class="monitor" src="https://i.imgur.com/OQL0NR3.png">
                <div class="three">
                    <div class="four"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/4yBw2n4.jpg"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
        <h1>Sample Text</h1>
    </div>
</div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This fixed the issue when resizing the height of the browser... but now the monitor doesn't scale (like it did before) when the browser width is resized.

I think I'm going with another approach but I appreciate your help with this!

Comment: Glade I could help you. :-)  I set monitor height 100% because to maintain the image aspect ratio. If not monitor image will stretch. I will update the answer and let you know if could find a solution for this. Sorry for the late reply.